# SPF ip4 mechanism

Tags: dns, ipv4, spf

I'm trying to get my head around SPF and the way it works. Found an example on [inmotionhosting.com](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/fighting-spam/create-custom-spf) which explains the ip4 mechanism. I cannot get the concept of prefix-length though. If, as per example in the link above,

```
"v=spf1 ip4:123.123.0.1/16 -all"
```

allows any IP address between 123.123.123.0.1 and 123.123.123.255.255, what IP addresses would be allowed for

```
"v=spf1 ip4:123.123.123.144/28 +all"
```

Comment: The `+` is the default mechanism and can be left off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix-length (also sometimes referenced as CIDR), simply tells that the first n bit of the IP-address has to match.

So 123.123.123.144/28 matches 123.123.123.144 - 123.123.123.159

With a /28 prefix-length only the last 4 (32 - 28) bits of the address is allowed to be different from the stated address.

Comment: As a side note this is a nice tool for calculating the above  http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr